# why d3.path().moveTo() function is undefined?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js

my function to generate path:

```
const getPath = (source, target) => {
    // console.log('path', path.moveTo(source.x, source.y));
    const path = d3.path()
      .moveTo(source.x, source.y)
      .lineTo(target.x, source.y)
      .lineTo(target.x, target.y)
      .toString();
    // console.log('path', path);
    return path;
  }
```

d3 import statement:

```
import * as d3 from "d3";
```

source and target structure:

```
{
  x: Number,
  y: Number
}
```

[image: this is the error i am getting]

why is moveTo undefined
what am i doing wrong?
i'm on react btw.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`moveTo` does not return anything, so its return value is `undefined`. It does not return the path, so you cannot do method chaining here. You can see this in the [source code](https://github.com/d3/d3-path/blob/6230b3c3952011ec917fcf5ba50c837051dc9b78/src/path.js#L18-L20) for `moveTo`:

```
moveTo: function(x, y) {
  this._ += "M" + (this._x0 = this._x1 = +x) + "," + (this._y0 = this._y1 = +y);
},
```

You can adjust your code to this and it should work:

```
const getPath = (source, target) => {
    const path = d3.path();

    path.moveTo(source.x, source.y);
    path.lineTo(target.x, source.y);
    path.lineTo(target.x, target.y);

    return path.toString();
  }
```